# How to install fabric.js on Rails 4 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, fabricjs

I'm newer in Rails and I just dont understand how to include this library in my project. I found gem 'fabric-rails', but it doesnt works to Rails 4, so, how could I install fabric.js?

Comment: The [installation instructions](https://github.com/davidjrice/fabric-rails) are **really** clear. They're dead simple and step-by-step. Which part specifically isn't working? All we can really do is copy-paste those instructions for you.

Comment: This gem doesnt works with Rails 4, when I'm trying to bundle it:

Comment: It should work with rails4. So: you get an error when doing `bundle` ? Which error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link to the remote CDN version by adding the following line to your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js" %>
```

**OR**

You can download the source code [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tags) and copy fabric.js or fabric.min.js from the dist folder to `vendor/assets/javascripts`

Then make sure it is required in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js(.coffee)`